Permission Denied Using SSH.NET (Identity File and Passphrase) from WinForms
Good day!
I am making a WinForms app using C# .NET 8.0.2 and have the NuGet SSH.NET ver. 24.0.0.
Manually, I can access a Linux remote machine from Windows using CMD using this in the CMD window:
ssh -i C:\Users\me_user\ .ssh\me@emaildomain.com the_user_name@192.168.XXX.XXX
Access that way works 100% fine, no issues.  I am required, once I enter that ssh command, to type in the PassPhrase twice in a row.  I suspect the first time is to 'unlock/decode' the me@emaildomain.com text file and the second is maybe part of two factor authentication by the remote machine.
I got the credentials from my company and the result was the me@emaildomain.com file that I downloaded and put in the subfolder indicated above.  I don't know all the details, but I believe it is SHA256.
From the cmd.exe launched ssh, I can send text commands (e.g., system motor drive 0x10AA) and the remote machine returns text that is correct (e.g., system OK "drive 0x10AA).
The me@emaildomain.com is a text file that is the OPENSSH key created in the .ssh subfolder shown in the path above when I got the credentials.  I do not have easy access to the remote machine to pull logs detailing what happens during a connection attempt, so I am hoping there might be clues based on what I have so far.  However it will be possible for me to get that access to logs (if the exist), just not in time for my next deadline.
When a button is clicked in my app's Form, the following code is called.  I am trying to establish a connection so I can programmatically send text commands (based on Text Boxes in the Form) to the remote machine and get text data back.  I am not trying to transfer file (so not FTP/SFTP).
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _privateKeyPath = @"C:\Users\me_user\.ssh\me@emaildomain.com";
    string _privateKeyPassPhrase = "ThePassPhrase";
    string _host = "192.168.XXX.XXX";
    string _username = "the_user_name";
    string _password = "ThePassPhrase";

    var keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(_privateKeyPath, _privateKeyPassPhrase);
    var keyFiles = new[] { keyFile };

    PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod pkAuth = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(_username, keyFiles);

    var methods = new AuthenticationMethod[] { new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(_username, _password), pkAuth};
    
    var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(_host, _username, methods);
 
    using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
    {
        
        client.Connect();
        
    }

When I run and click the button I get this Exception:
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: 'Permission denied (publickey).'
I have tried various orderings of the authentication methods, so they get put into the array and passed to the ConnectionInfo var in different orders, etc.
Initially, I was using this for the client:
using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
but then I realized it wasn't SFTP I was after (no file transfer), just SSH for commands back/forth, so I changed it to SshClient(connectionInfo).
If I deliberately botch the first PassPhrase, I get a different Exception:  That the PassPhrase is incorrect, which makes sense and at least tells me that that part of the SSH.NET stuff is working and 'recognizes' the PassPhrase is correct when it is.
As an entirely different approach:
I have also tried to create a process and call "cmd.exe", then send text that is the ssh connection string I show above.  I can get so far as the PassPhrase (which I can actually type in to the created command (console?) window, and that was enticing.  But then nothing comes back after the second instance of typing the PassPhrase.  and apparently nothing I type gets through, either (but there are no obvious error messages).  There is text on the created command window mentrioning something like 'pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because...'.  I tried adding a -t after the ssh for this approach, but still no joy.
I have tried to search for similar issues, and that is how I came to use the code I have above to try and make the connection.  But I have not seen anything with a whole different approach to try so I will appreciate any tips or pointers.
Thank you in advance!
I was asked to inspect the -vvv log (which I just learned about), so I am including some of that here (starting with once I am prompted to provide the passphrase the first time).  I am still not sure why the code I have is failing but from the log I can see that the first passphrase entry indeed makes the decrypted key available to the remote machine, and the second acts another factor to let me in.  Here is the log starting with the first passphrase entry:
C:\Users\PC_USER>ssh -vvv -i C:\Users\PC_USER\.ssh\USER_NAME@domain.com SSH_USER@192.168.8.2
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/PC_USER/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.8.2 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.8.2 [192.168.8.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/PC_USER/.ssh/USER_NAME@domain.com.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\PC_USER\\.ssh\\USER_NAME@domain.com type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/PC_USER/.ssh/USER_NAME@domain.com-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\PC_USER\\.ssh\\USER_NAME@domain.com-cert type 6
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.8.2:22 as 'SSH_USER'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\PC_USER/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\PC_USER/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.8.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/PC_USER/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:<41 Alphanumeric Characters stripped from here>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\PC_USER/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\PC_USER/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.8.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/PC_USER/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host '192.168.8.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\PC_USER/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\PC_USER\\.ssh\\USER_NAME@domain.com  explicit
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\PC_USER\\.ssh\\USER_NAME@domain.com ECDSA-CERT SHA256:<Instance of Group of same 43 Alphanumeric Chars> explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\PC_USER\\.ssh\\USER_NAME@domain.com
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\PC_USER\.ssh\USER_NAME@domain.com':
----I manually type in the passphrase here and hit Enter----
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ECDSA SHA256:----Instance of Group of same 43 Alphanumeric Chars----
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\PC_USER\\.ssh\\USER_NAME@domain.com ECDSA-CERT SHA256:----Instance of Group of same 43 Alphanumeric Chars---- explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\PC_USER\\.ssh\\USER_NAME@domain.com ECDSA-CERT SHA256:----Instance of Group of same 43 Alphanumeric Chars---- explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ECDSA-CERT SHA256:----Instance of Group of same 43 Alphanumeric Chars----
debug2: sign_and_send_pubkey: using private key "C:\\Users\\PC_USER\\.ssh\\USER_NAME@domain.com" for certificate
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\PC_USER\.ssh\USER_NAME@domain.com':
----I manually type in the passphrase here and hit Enter----
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.8.2 ([192.168.8.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:437 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: cert: key options: agent-forwarding command port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: cert: key options: agent-forwarding command port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
SSH_USER@0123456789AB:~$ ----I am connected, so here I type in a text command string and hit Enter----
Debug: ----here the remote machine replies with a correct string----
SSH_USER@0123456789AB:~$


Thank you for taking the time to read and give the -vvv advice Martin!  That definitely gets me more understanding but I still am stuck trying to get this working.

Yes, I am typing in the exact same passphrase twice in a row when I use Windows cmd.exe to start SSH (which works fine every time).  And you are correct about the log being incomplete, I assumed the most important log bits started when the passphrase prompt first appeared and was worried the whole thing would be too long.  Please see that I updated the question with the complete log as it came from the -vvv switch (again, I only changed specific items for privacy).  Thank you again!

Yes, it looks like I might be.  It turns out that the .ssh folder has a key file (referred to above) as well as a XXXXX.com-cert.pub file (which I now recognize as a certificate file if I understand correctly).  I then saw you had a answer to the question ".NET SSH with certificate authentication" and that makes we think maybe I can't use SSH.NET to complete this job.  There is also https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/479 which makes me think what I need is maybe coming soon, but not available today.  Again, thanks for helping me get up to speed fast!
